# "Verification Required" when installing free apps?

Tags: iphone, mac-appstore, ios-appstore

When I tried to install a free app, AppStore says:

> **Verification Required**
>
> Before you can make purchases, you must tap Continue to sign in, then
>   verify your payment info.

I never had this problem before. How do I install free apps without providing Apple with my credit card information?

Comment: I'd say this is a generic message, do you actually have to enter your credit card information when you go through the verification steps? It is indeed possible to create an Apple ID without a credit card, see "Creating an iTunes Store, App Store, iBookstore, and Mac App Store account without a credit card" at http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2534.

Comment: @jaume it shows me the last 4 digits of my credit card, without me entering anything. I already have an apple ID, is there any way to disassociate all credit card information with apple so that they won't bother me with credit card issues (like this) again?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, see my answer below for details.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It is indeed possible to create an Apple ID without a credit card, see "Creating an iTunes Store, App Store, iBookstore, and Mac App Store account without a credit card" at http://support.apple.com/kb/ht2534.

If you entered credit card information in the past you can dissociate it from your Apple ID as follows.

**On an iOS device**

1. Open Settings.
2. Tap iTunes & App Stores:

   [image]
3. Tap your account and select "View Apple ID".
4. Select `Payment information`:

   [image]
5. Select `None`:

   [image]
6. Confirm with `Done`.

**On a Mac**

1. Open App Store.app:

   [image]
2. Select menu Store>View My Account.
3. In the Apple ID Summary section locate the Payment Information line and click `Edit >`:

   [image]
4. Select `None` as payment method:

   [image]

   [image]
5. Click `Done` to confirm.

If you don't see a "none" option, you may need to disable family sharing and then try the above steps again.

Comment: Does windows have an App Store.app? Are there ways to do it simply through a browser?

Comment: No, you must do it from your Mac. You can also use an iOS device, there is a similar procedure for iPhone/iPad: Open  Settings, tap iTunes & App Stores, tap your account and select "View Apple ID", select "Payment information" and select "None". Confirm with `Done`.

Comment: thanks it's working. That should have been the answer though, since not everyone with an iPhone has a mac.

Comment: That's true, I just thought the verification message came from the **Mac** App Store, a wrong assumption from my part. I've edited the answer and added a section for iOS devices.

Comment: This works indeed. I never had entered any payment data ("None" was selected from beginning on). But I was asked to confirm my payment info even for free apps, although it was still set to "None". I think this happens, because I'm have logged in with a completely another account but which has credit card info entered. I guess that even when logging out and in with an account without payment info, the app store / itunes stores the info in a cache or so, so it must be updated by re-saving your account information. Now it works for me too. So if you still have problems: update your account info.

Comment: I have no payment method associated with my account but I still get this message.