# Login in the app store in Turkey

Tags: iphone

I recently purchased a Iphone 5 in turkey, and when i try to log in into the app store is asking me for a credit or debit card. 
How do I by-pass this? Why I get asked for such info?
Thank you.

Comment: Is `None` an option for the credit card type?

Answer (score 1):

In the **settings for your Apple ID** there is a payment options selection, where you can chose **none**.  You can find this in the menu called **Settings** in your iPhone.  You may also have to check the settings under iCloud.

There is a really [super answer here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/94433/176465), check it out for lots of details, even pictures; this is for the most part, the same on the latest versions.

I understand, you want to just get free "apps!"

If you might also want to pay for things sometime, another really nice option, is that you can go to almost every kind of shop (even a convenience store) and buy an iTunes *gift card* with *cash,* which will come with instructions about how to add this credit into your iTunes (and therefore also automatically your "App Store") account.

Comment: Please mark the checkmark icon, so the question is "solved," if this was helpful.  I would also like to edit/rename the question; depending on more information, because if this is all you needed, it doesn't matter where you bought the phone.  Is the phone already logged in to the iTunes account of the *previous owner*?